# Install additional dependencies to docker image directly or with multistage?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I want to create an "optimal" production image, therefore using `debian:buster-slim`. But I need two additional dependencies: `pgrep` and `lftp`.

Question: is it better to directly install them into the image? Or download + prepare them somehow in a previous multistage build step, and then just simply copy their *executables* to the production image?

The direct approach would be:

```
FROM debian:buster-slim
RUN set -xe \
    && apt update \
    && apt install --yes --no-install-recommends \
        procps \
        lftp \
    && rm --recursive --force /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Could I do better in terms of an optimized image?

Comment: There's no point in using a multi-stage build for what you're doing here. A multi-stage build is only useful if you're only copying specific assets from an earlier stage (like the result of a build process).

Comment: My major concern is that every dependency installation leads to fragments left in the image, that are not really needed. That's why I'm looking for a way to only "copy" the two additional dependencies from a prior multi stage step.

Comment: Installing procps and lftp might install dependencies like shared libraries etc. You'd need to know all the installed dependencies to know what to copy. It'll be hell to maintain.